# Is it possible to link more than one Excel file to the same Access database table?

Tags: excel, vba, database, ms-access

We are having an important issue at my organization right now. Up to this point (and since it is a small business) they have been using an Excel macro-enabled file with some forms coded in VBA to record sales, expenses, manage inventory, etc. Although it is not the best solution, so far it has been doing the job. Now, they'd like to implement a second computer to manage the business "database" simultaneously.

The first thing I thought was to share the `Workbook` locally through the legacy `Share` function in Excel and force the file to refresh before the VBA code makes any change to avoid entry duplication in the tables. However, this functionality is very limited and can't refresh the `Workbook` as often as I'd like.

I searched for a few days and found a few "band-aid" solutions for this using just Excel and some web query, but that just seems destined to fail. So, what I thought could be a viable solution is to link the exact same Excel file on more computers to the same Access database, which will be a lot easier to manage. I found out that Access offers the function to link an Excel file to a database, and any changes made to original Excel file will be automatically updated in the database. Then, you can also retrieve the data from said database back to Excel to keep everything updated on all computers. I believe if there would be a way to link the Excel file on every computer to the same Access database which will be hosted locally, and then update Excel back before making any new changes this could work. My problem is that, even though all tables have the same name (they belong to the same Excel file), Access decides to use only one source to manage the database.

Basically, I'd like to use and Excel macro-enabled file as the front-end interface, and Access as the back-end database. I'm well aware that this, by far, isn't the best solution, but it'll be a while before we have the time and resources to make a proper database using SQL. I would highly appreciate any suggestions to sort this out. I'm also aware of the risks involved, but considering that no more than 4 computers would be connected at the same time I believe the risks wouldn't be as high as trying to do this at a corporate level.

Comment: Your data goes in the Access database file. Import it in to the database once then archive the old Excel files. Now you can make new Excel files to view the data but this is a one-way, read-only operation. Do not use Excel as the Front end. Design a proper access DB FE for data entry. You will end up with 3 files, minimum. 1, the data in the DB BE, 2 the FE in a separate access DB file. 3 the views that users are accustomed to using in Excel.

Comment: This is more of a Software Engineering and Database design question. It does not pertain to a piece of code. As such it's likely going to be closed as off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I recommend eliminating Excel component. Build frontend with an Access file. Also note, SQL is not a database, it is a language used by many database platforms, including Access. Perhaps you mean SQLServer or MySQL. Access can still serve as frontend when data is migrated to other platform.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I was specifically trying to avoid using Access as the user interface as well because coding all the forms from scratch would take at least a few weeks but I suppose there is no other way.

Comment: @June7 You are totally right about the server denomination. I was just trying to refer to SQL as the language and leave the option open to choose a proper platform in the future. I think we'll go with MySQL. Thank you for that suggestions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the sample code below and feel free to modify anything to suit your needs.

```
Sub ImportDataFromExcel()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
        "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Coding\Integrating Access and Excel and SQL Server\Access & Excel & SQL Server\" & _
        "EXCEL AND ACCESS AND SQL SERVER\Excel & Access\Select, Insert, Update & Delete\Northwind.mdb"
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open strConn
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
        lastcolumn = .Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(lastrow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))
    End With
        
        'therow = 1
        
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            'r = rng.Row
            'If r > 1 Then
                strSQL = "UPDATE PersonInformation SET " & _
                    "FName='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "LName='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "Address='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "Age=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value & " WHERE " & _
                    "ID=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
                conn.Execute strSQL
            'End If
            'r = r + 1
        Next i
        
    
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Also...

```
Sub ExportDataToExcel()
   Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim myRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim strConn As String

   strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Coding\Integrating Access and Excel and SQL Server\" & _
   "Access & Excel & SQL Server\EXCEL AND ACCESS AND SQL SERVER\Excel & Access\Select, Insert, Update & Delete\Northwind.mdb"

   Set myRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

   FocusRow = ActiveCell.Row
   With myRecordset
       .Open "SELECT * FROM PersonInformation WHERE ID=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value, _
         strConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
         ' This assumes that ID is a number field. If it is a text field, use
         ' .Open "SELECT * FROM PersonInformation WHERE ID='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value & "'", _
         strConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
         
      .Fields("ID").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & FocusRow).Value
      .Fields("FName").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & FocusRow).Value
      .Fields("LName").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & FocusRow).Value
      .Fields("Address").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & FocusRow).Value
      .Fields("Age").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & FocusRow).Value
      .Update
      .Close
   End With
   Set myRecordset = Nothing
   Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Now, if you want to upgrade to a real database, and use SQL Server, you can use the code below.

```
Sub InsertIntoSqlServer()

'Declare some variables
Dim cnn As adodb.Connection
Dim cmd As adodb.Command
Dim strSQL As String

'Create a new Connection object
Set cnn = New adodb.Connection

'Set the connection string
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS"
'cnn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=Your_Server_Name;DATABASE=Your_Database_Name;Trusted_Connection=Yes"

'Create a new Command object
Set cmd = New adodb.Command

'Open the Connection to the database
cnn.Open

'Associate the command with the connection
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

'Tell the Command we are giving it a bit of SQL to run, not a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Create the SQL
strSQL = "UPDATE TBL SET JOIN_DT = '2013-01-22' WHERE EMPID = 2"

'Pass the SQL to the Command object
cmd.CommandText = strSQL


'Execute the bit of SQL to update the database
cmd.Execute

'Close the connection again
cnn.Close

'Remove the objects
Set cmd = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This is brilliant and perfectly suits my needs, not to the mention that the code is very clean and easy to understand. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Sure. Happy to help you out here.